# Database name not getting logged while using mariadb audit plugin with dbeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I have a RDS set up with mariabd audit plugin. The setup is working as expected with mysql commandline and mysql workbench. The expected log format is:

```
20210824 05:49:46,ip-10-xx-xx-xx,admin,18.x.x.x,8917,1590713,QUERY,test_env_db,'create table stocklist100 (id int, name varchar(20))',0
```

And I am getting the expected log format while using mysql commandline or mysql workbench

But with the Dbeaver client, I am getting the log like this:

```
20210824 05:34:47,ip--3-182,admin,183.x.x.x,8912,1590009,QUERY,,'/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.1.5 - SQLEditor <Script-4.sql> */ alter table final add column ksentiwnr varchar(1)',0
```

It doesn't have the database name in the log and also it adds some comments like:

`/* ApplicationName=DBeaver 21.1.5 - SQLEditor <Script-4.sql> */`

Is there way to solve this with some configuration with DBeaver or is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the connector from mysql to mariadb connector in DBeaver. While creating the connection in DBeaver choose `mariadb` instead of `mysql`. Now the log format is matching the format which is recieved while using mysql workbench/ mysql command line client.

PS: I don't know the exact reason how this worked, further clarifications are welcome.

Comment: Is this an answer that actually solved your problem?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.